# i'm using axios post request in Formik,and return me 400 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, formik

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooKBB.png)
pleas look at img,i try to use it , but its dosent work, and i cant understand why

```
<Formik        
initialValues={{email: "", password: "", firstname: "",
           lastname: "", passwordConfirm: ""}}


onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting}) => {
        console.log(values);

        // Send a POST r`enter code here`equest
        axios.post('http://212.42.212.29:3001/auth/register', values, {
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error.response);
            });

    }}
  
>
```

Comment: 400 - Bad request. Make sure you have given right endpoint and also check whether the backend is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in Formik, I have written value names mistakenly

```
   <Formik 
     initialValues={{email: "", password: "", firstname: "", lastname: "", 
       passwordConfirm: ""}}
     >
```

**should be **

```
   <Formik 
    initialValues={
          {email: "", 
           password: "", 
         **firstName: "",** 
         **lastName:""**, 
     passwordConfirm: ""}}
   >
```